# how to split up a pandas series off of every two words in python

Tags: python, pandas

if I have a pandas dataframe with a description of an issue, how can I split each value into two separate words at a time?

e.g

| Subject Number | Issue |
| --- | --- |
| 30493 | "This subject was unable to keep his head straight in the MRI" |
| 43253 | "This subject fell asleep thus ended up with poor data |

and I want it to be like

| Subject Number | Issue |
| --- | --- |
| 30493 | "This subject", "was unable", "to keep", "his head", "straight in", "the MRI" |
| 43253 | "This subject", "fell asleep", "thus ended", "up with", "poor data" |

The pandas series here would be df["issue"]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible way to do it.

```
import re
df['Issue'] = df['Issue'].map(lambda string: list(filter(None,re.split(r"(\w+\s\w+)\s",string))))
print(df)

   Subject Number                                              Issue
0          30493  [This subject, was unable, to keep, his head, ...
1          43253  [This subject, fell asleep, thus ended, up wit...
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a single regex:

```
df['Issue'] = df['Issue'].str.findall(r'((?:\S+\s*?){2})\s*')
```

Output:

```
   Subject Number                                                                Issue
0           30493  [This subject, was unable, to keep, his head, straight in, the MRI]
1           43253          [This subject, fell asleep, thus ended, up with, poor data]
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function `split_str_to_2grams` to do it for a single string, then do `df['Issue'].apply(split_str_to_2grams)`. Untested but try this:

```
def split_str_to_2grams(string: str) -> list[str]:
    l = string.split()
    return [" ".join(l[2*i:2*i+2]) for i in range(len(l))//2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but it will get your desired string:

```
df.issue = df.issue.str.split().apply(lambda x: ', '.join('"' + i + ' ' + j + '"' for i, j in zip(x[::2], x[1::2])))
```

Output:

```
   Subject Number                                              Issue
0           30493  "This subject", "was unable", "to keep", "his ...
1           43253  "This subject", "fell asleep", "thus ended", "...
```

Or if you actually want a list:

```
df.Issue.str.split().apply(lambda x: [' '.join([i,j]) for i, j in zip(x[::2], x[1::2])])

...

0    [This subject, was unable, to keep, his head, ...
1    [This subject, fell asleep, thus ended, up wit...
Name: Issue, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
span = 2 # every how many words

df['type'].apply(lambda x: [" ".join(x.split()[i:i+span]) for i in range(0, len(x.split()), span)])
```

Output:

```
0    [This subject, was unable, to keep, his head, ...
1    [This subject, fell asleep, thus ended, up wit...
```

Note: I am assuming with the output you mean a list of every two words not exactly the shape with quotations and commas